# Is it possible to reset a PolynomialRing variable after you give it a value?

Tags: math, polynomials, sage

```
sage: R17.<x> = PolynomialRing(GF(17))
sage: f1 = R17(x + 10)
sage: f1 = x + 10
sage: f1
sage: x + 10
```

So now `f1` is a polynomial.

But I then give a value to `x`

```
sage: x = 25
```

Then I try to define another polynomial `f2` in the same way I defined `f1`

```
sage: f2 = R17(x + 15)
sage: f2
6
```

But because I have given a value 25 to `x`, sage doesn't seem to treat the statement as a polynomial definition.

When I try to evaluate f2 at `x = 1`, it doesn't do that.

```
sage: f2(1)
6
```

I have to redefine the ring before I can get further

```
sage: R17.<x> = PolynomialRing(GF(17))
sage: f2 = R17(x + 15)
sage: f2
x + 15
sage: f2(1)
16
```

Is there a simpler way to 'reset' `x` - i.e. remove the value it's been given, so it's treated as a variable again?

Comment: Not an answer but as an alternative, one may be able to simply avoid giving values to x.

Comment: Note that once you do `x = 25`, you have completely overwritten the old definition: Sage has no memory of what it used to be. The answer by @MvG provides good ways to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [inject_variables](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/structure/sage/structure/category_object.html#sage.structure.category_object.CategoryObject.inject_variables):

```
sage: R17.inject_variables()
```

This should reset `x` to be the generator of the ring. As an alternative you should also be able to use

```
sage: x = R17.gens()[0]
```

to explicitly reset the variable `x` to refer to the first generator of the ring.